# Unix to execute program on WAN IP update

Tags: daemon, wide-area-network, amazon-route53

How do I access the current IP address? Is there a way to execute a program every time it changes? **I want to make a program that whenever my IP changes, it will use the Amazon Route 53 API and update a record set with its current IP address.** Basically, whenever my IP changes, it will tell amazon where its at so that traffic can be directed to it. I have done some perl, python, go, and bash scripting. Though I'd be most comfortable with python or bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check your current IP with the `ifconfig` command. However, if you're behind a NAT that won't show you much.

The best you can do is poll something external that will tell you what your translated IP address is. WhatIsMyIP.com provides a service for doing this. See their [IP Automation Rules](http://www.whatismyip.com/faq/automation.asp).

Poll both Route 53 and WhatIsMyIP no more frequently than every 300 seconds. If they are different then update Route 53.